# Unit Testing for pgxpool

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, go

I am looking to write unit tests for Go code that uses pgxpool to interact with a postgres database. Is there a test framework that will stand up a dummy or mock database to test on?

I am aware of a package called `pgxpoolmock`. The problem is, there is no way to test actual production code, as a pool from `pgxpool` cannot be casted to the type `pgxpoolmock` (or can it?)

Comment: Mocking is not casting and still requires your code to be written in a way (ideally using interfaces where needed) so that you can swap backends. My personal preference is to use "storage pattern" where I abstract all data access for my app. Then, to test app I don't need database at all and to test store I trust pgx testsuite when it comes to communication with DB engine and use integration testing on real-world DB engine where it comes to queries and logic - e.g. in Docker.

Answer (score 0):

`pgxpoolmock` is using an interface `pgxpoolmock.PgxPool`. This interface has all the methods that are being used in the `pgxpool.Pool` struct. `pgxpoolmock.MockPgxPool` is implementing that interface. `pgxpoolmock.NewMockPgxPool(ctrl)` returning a struct that implements the interface `pgxpoolmock.PgxPool`. So if you want to use `pgxpoolmock`, you have to use `pgxpoolmock.PgxPool` in your application code not in test code alone.